# Сравнение двух словарей 20+ тыс элементов

Tags: python-3.x, оптимизация, словари, сравнение, multiprocessing

Имеется 2 списка словарей, словари имеют одинаковые ключи: {*'name'*: * , *'price'*: * , *'have'*: *} Мне необходимо получить список вида [*'name'*, *'price1'*, *'price2'*] для каждого совпадения словарей по значению ключа *'name'*.
Вот мой код:

```py
def matching(data1, data2):
    for item_1 in data1:
        for item_2 in data2:
            if item_1['have'] != 0 and item_2['have'] != 0:
                if item_1['name'] == item_2['name']:
                    item = [item_1['name'], item_1['price'], item_2['price']]
                    profit(item)
                    break
```

Дальше идет подсчёт профита, сортировка и вывод в таблицу. 
Данный код вполне рабочий, НО! Но это так только для словарей примерно 5-6 тысяч элементов, а когда мне нужно сравнить 2 словаря из больше чем 20 тысяч элементов то все зависает минут так на 5 и там уже как бог рандома даст: или вылет, или таки получу свои данные.
Пытался прикрутить *multiprocessing.Pool* для решения проблемы, но к сожалению моих знаний не хватило для этого, так как я только недавно окунулся в дивный мир Python. Подскажите в том направлении ли я копаю или есть лучшие решения моей проблемы?

Небольшой пример:

```
data1 = [{'name': 'bananas', 'price':21, 'have': 10},
         {'name': 'apples', 'price': 14, 'have': 0}, 
         {'name':'oranges', 'price': 16, 'have':7}]    

data2 = [{'name': 'pinaples', 'price': 14, 'have': 4}, 
         {'name':'bananas', 'price': 17, 'have': 6}, 
         {'name':'apples', 'price': 17, 'have': 4}]
```

Из сравнения этих двух списков я должен получить:
*item = ['bananas', 21, 17]*

Питон 32 битный, 8гб оперативки, в качестве IDE использую PyCharm.

Comment: `20+ тис` это 20000 (20к, двадцать тысяч)? Питон 32 битный? Сколько оперативной памяти?

Comment: можете привести в вопросе маленькие примеры входных данных (по 3-5 элементов) и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе? Что-то мне подсказывает, что решение на Pandas будет работать на порядок быстрее...

Comment: кстати да, у вас Python, надеюсь, 64-битный?

Comment: А зачем вы делаете поиск в цикле? Потому все и медленно. Это же словари

Comment: Цикл 20тыщ*20тыщ = в худшем случае ~400 миллионов итераций...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример с использованием [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import random
import pandas as pd    #   pip install pandas

random.seed(31415926535897932384626)
data1 = [{'name':f'n{i}', 'price':random.randint(10, 10000), 'have':random.randint(0, 10)} 
         for i in range(1, 50001)]
random.seed(2718281828459045)
data2 = [{'name':f'n{i}', 'price':random.randint(10, 10000), 'have':random.randint(0, 10)} 
         for i in range(1, 45001)]

d1 = pd.DataFrame(data1).sample(frac=1)
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data2).sample(frac=1)

res = (d1.query("have > 0").drop("have",1)
       .merge(d2.query("have > 0").drop("have",1), 
              on="name", suffixes=["1", "2"])
       .eval("profit = price2 - price1"))
```

Результат:

```
In [32]: res
Out[32]:
         name  price1  price2  profit
0      n19094    8593    6234   -2359
1      n33636    3862    8823    4961
2      n12872    3691    2863    -828
3      n44005    9233    3296   -5937
4      n23220    3276    9721    6445
5      n14919    8880     145   -8735
6      n36834    5800    2677   -3123
...       ...     ...     ...     ...
37146   n5697    3169    2895    -274
37147  n34615    1815    2515     700
37148  n44357    5984    5343    -641
37149  n41498    6251    5575    -676
37150  n27374     416    6345    5929
37151  n37631    3943    8806    4863
37152  n32704    1047    1633     586

[37153 rows x 4 columns]
```

Время выполнения для списков состоящих из 50K и 45K словарей:

```
In [33]: %%timeit
    ...: res = (d1.query("have > 0").drop("have",1)
    ...:        .merge(d2.query("have > 0").drop("have",1),
    ...:               on="name", suffixes=["1", "2"])
    ...:        .eval("profit = price2 - price1"))
    ...:
    ...:
49.6 ms ± 1.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

**UPDATE:** пример с входными данными из вопроса:

```
In [22]: d1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

In [23]: d2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

In [24]: res = (d1.query("have > 0").drop("have",1)
    ...:        .merge(d2.query("have > 0").drop("have",1),
    ...:               on="name", suffixes=["1", "2"]))

In [25]: res
Out[25]:
      name  price1  price2
0  bananas      21      17

In [26]: result = res.values.tolist()

In [27]: result
Out[27]: [['bananas', 21, 17]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ты для каждого элемента из первого списка пробегаешь по второму. Т. е трудоёмкость решения у тебя `O(n*m)` где `n` - длинна первого списка, `m` = второго.

Для ускорения, можно перевести второй список в словарь по имени, тогда трудоёмкость будет `O(n)`

```
d_data = {o['name']: o for o in data2}
for item_1 in data1:
    if item_1['have'] == 0:
        continue
    item_2 = d_data.get(item_1['name'])
    if item_2 and item_2['have'] != 0:
        item = [item_1['name'], item_1['price'], item_2['price']]
        profit(item)
```